# How can I disable my 2002 Ford Explorer so someone with a key can't start it?

Tags: engine, ford, ignition, starter, explorer

A person at my house continually moves my 2002 Ford Explorer from the driveway to the street without permission. The key is shared and must remain easily accessible. Personal issues aside, is there a way we can disable my truck so he can't move it, by removing a plug or cap to disable our vehicle like in the movies? What would be a few options?

Comment: I don't really get the point of leaving keys AND disabling the car. Car still won't move, so the effect is the same as hiding keys.

Comment: He's just trying to be nice to this person, but at the same time, his access will be disabled. It's like those people who go out with us and never pay or share any bills. We just tell them we're not going out anymore. He wants everyone to move his SUV when required, just not this listed person. In a polite manner, he'll claim the SUV is not running anymore, and it'll be an inside joke amongst themselves.

Comment: Assuming everyone involved are grownups, this is really simple to deal with. Tell him his actions are costing you money (tickets) and it has to stop **or he needs to move out**.

Comment: Putting it very simply: **this guy isn't your friend, he's a dick**. He's being incredibly selfish and taking advantage of your good nature. If he's being so lazy that his preferred solution to a problem is to cost you large amounts of money, he's almost certainly doing other things you aren't aware of yet. Kick him out immediately.

Comment: Do any of the answers [in this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/15427/4152) help you out?

Comment: some friend. have a talk with your 'friend' and tell him to a) stop doing something without your consent especially after repeated requests and b) behave like a responsible adult, show some respect, and learn to accommodate and work with other people instead of acting like a narcissist. if that fails (ie he actually is a narcissist), explain to him that if he continues to ignore your request you will be forced to take physical measures to prevent him from being able to move the car (ie kill switch), for which he will be obliged to pay. perhaps also remind him whose house he is living in.

Comment: I have often heard it said that you cannot solve social issues with technology and think that it applies here as well. You are about to start an arms race that you can't win. Either you succeed and he will be annoyed and pester you or you don't and will be annoyed yourself. I'd recommend you head over to [IPS.SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) and ask how you can work this out together or find another way.

Comment: The long preamble belongs to https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/ , I'm surprised you all address that interpersonal problem, that is completely irrelevant to the mechanics. The **actual question** is the second paragraph, and the only persons addressing it are Solar Mike and  Numair Aidroos.

Comment: Have you considered putting the keys to your car into a safe which trustworthy people are given the combination?  Given the toxicity of the situation, I don't think the offense of physically denying him access to the keys is going to make it all that much worse than it already is.

Comment: Put the keys in a different place. Tell all your roommates where the keys are, except for him.

Comment: I don't understand this question - probably due to culture differences. What does this guy do? He drives to your apartment, finds no place to park, gets out of his car, gets into yours, parks your car somewhere away, gets back to his car and parks in place previously occupied by your car? That's not laziness; that's malice. Or am I just missing something?

Comment: I think you should all park outside the driveway until this unwanted guest is no longer there. The inconvenience will be a constant reminder to you, so it probably will not take long.

Comment: BTW. You allow random strangers to move your car?

Comment: Sounds like an incredible back-story concocted so you can learn how to disable someone else's car.

Comment: The answer is to tell him to move out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't really ask a mechanical question.

Comment: @SteveRacer: It clearly does, but for some reason most ignore that part of OP and dive into the interpersonal question which simply wasn't asked.

Comment: Agreed, @SteveRacer, and I've edited to address this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I suspect that OP wants to manipulate a vehicle not in his legitimate possession since he ignores the obvious solution of hiding his keys

Comment: @zaibis The problem is, the asker clearly states that he has a human behavior problem (A person at my house continually moves my 2002 Ford Explorer from the driveway to the street without permission) and then proceeds to ask for a technical solution to this problem. Both aspects ARE present in the original question.  The real problem is there's no way to solve the original problem solely with a technical solution. Human behavior problems require human solutions.

Comment: @barbecue: as said, then would migrating the post be an option, but I see no benefit for anyone by imply answering a question that wasn't asked.

Comment: What defines "reasonably accessible?"  Are we talking about some legalese clause where someone wrote down a location the keys had to be in, or are we talking about a practical concern that individuals need to be able to move the car.  If it's the latter, then what distinguishes hiding the keys from disabling the car, given that both of them require knowing a shared secret to make the car move?

Comment: It's defined as "irrelevant to the question", @CortAmmon, because this is a site about working on cars, not how to manage a household. But for the full story if you're curious, see [the earlier revisions of the question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/revisions/48033/6).

Comment: @JoshCaswell I don't think it's irrelevant because the definition of "accessible" is important here.  I suppose we could ignore it entirely, in which case a valid answer is "install a club, and hide *that* key."  There's clearly some unspecified expectation about the usability of the vehicle.  Any remotely out-of-the-box answer needs to know where the box is.

Comment: In addition to such negative requirements which would make an answer invalid, it is also essential to understanding the positive requirements.  There is a level of accessibility the OP wants to prevent.  Is merely removing the positive lead of the battery sufficient?  Cars don't start too good without it!  Without understanding the OP's opinions about accessibility, the question is hopelessly broad.  I can disable the car by removing its tires, or by removing fuses, or by siphoning all of the gas out of the tank...

Comment: How do we know, this person is not the very friend whom they are not wanting to let to use the car?

Answer (score 26):

If your friend is moving your vehicle without your consent and does so deliberately your friend is committing a crime. Vehicle theft. If you are asleep when this happens then consent was not given. I would suggest that you have a police officer have a long discussion with this individual about this. If this individual when moving your vehicle hits another vehicle and damages it.  Since you are the owner of the vehicle you are responsible and your insurance rates will go up. As for disabling start looking into installing a kill switch . Also if you get parking tickets as a result....get him to pay for them.

Comment: Please read what was typed earlier. Everyone and anyone who is a resident is allowed to move the vehicle (02 Explorer), there must be a parking arrangement which calls for this, hence the keys are hung in a visible spot.

Comment: @NumairAidroos That statement contains a contradiction in terms. Either the keys are available for everybody to move the car, or the car is disabled, *either* by removing the keys, cutting the wires, removing the distributor, whatever. You can't accomplish both objectives at the same time. The question is self-contradictory.

Comment: EJP, this is too much trouble explaining for a lost cause and no monetary gain. But for my peace, here it is. 1 fellow should not be able to move the car, rest all should be allowed. Simple as that. Whatever we recommend, Dave will share with the others, not with just that 1 person. .

Comment: @NumairAidroos It still doesn't make sense. If you can remove "object X" from the car to disable it, but have that object be accessible by everyone but the so-called "friend", then you can arrange for the keys to be accessible by everyone but the friend. Whatever you can do to the car, you can do to the keys. This seems like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/214708).

Comment: This answer really doesn't address the main question.  Simply stating "install a kill switch" doesn't help.  It's not like he can go to an auto parts store, buy a kill switch and plug it in.  That's what he needs help with from our site - not legal advice.

Comment: @JBentley this is the XY problem to end all XY problems.

Comment: I agree with all of the "kick this guy out" comments, but if you must go the technology route, why not put your keys in a key lock box like vacation rental properties and such use? Everybody but the jerk gets the combination... These can be had for $20 or less.

Comment: Very well John C. I agree with this part of the deal. Exceptional suggestion. Might I convince you to put this up as an Answer?

Comment: @JBentley There is a difference. The "friend" knows there are keys - so if you hide them, a) he can start looking b) he might know that OP deliberately hides them from him. If the car just doesn't start he won't draw that conclusion (probably and at first). OP tried to come up with a very defensive strategy. I don't think it will work to solve the problem (not for more than a couple days at most, when it becomes clear that the car does work for others), but there is a difference to hiding the keys!

Comment: @stannius cool! So if we solve this one *XY Complete Problem*, then we can solve all of them. Wicked!

Comment: @EJP disabling car is better than hiding keys. It enables you to troll your "friend": *"Hi, I noticed that you frequently move my car. It doesn't start anymore - have you tried to move it lately?"*

Comment: This is not vehicle theft.Theft includes the intent to deprive the rightful owner of it.

Comment: @Loong so you can avoid being charged with theft just by taking the owner with you? Great!

Comment: No theft, but still [illegal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joyride_(crime)).

Answer (score 26):

[image]

I'll make it very simple for you, Dave.

Just remove the relay highlighted, in yellow, from the diagram above.

This goes to the starter.

Comment: And how are you going to prevent the "friend" from putting the relay back? Whatever you do to prevent that, you can do to the keys.

Comment: This will not be accessible to that fellow. Only others will know about this hack. He doesn't want that fellow to know he's blocked his access. Now he'll remain polite.

Comment: @NumairAidroos What if the "friend" uses this website and figures it out?

Comment: I'm not sure how many people will have that relay in their pocket for "just in case" reasons. You could also remove the battery completely from the vehicle, distributor cap too.

Comment: Isn't he going to notice that the car is still being moved? Just not by him

Comment: Though if he still has a key, the OPs "friend" can unlock the Explorer and push it out of the way. What does he care if it gets towed away instead of a ticket?

Comment: Hann Fist, one wheel can be locked using a wheel lock bar.

Comment: @NumairAidroos yeah, just get one of those steering wheel lock bar things, and put the key where this guy doesn't know where it is! Yay!

Comment: Never mind finding this site, all the problem maker would need to do was watch someone else pop the hood/etc and open the fuse box prior to starting the vehicle.  From there figuring out the problem is the empty socket where the relay was yanked is easy even if he doesn't see exactly what you do in it.

Comment: We'll gift him a biometric lock. Send us the money via PayPal.

Comment: @JBentley: That is neither the question nor a problem that would be on topic on this site.

Comment: @DanNeely - Thanks for the troll... but fuse boxes are not inside the hood.  They are in the interior of the vehicle.  Have been for 50 years... not sure why you would make that comment here except to troll.

Comment: @Chad Never owned a ford, but my last car (06 buick lacross) had 2 fuse boxes; one of them under the hood. IIRC all the relays were in that one, with the passenger compartment box only having fuses for some of the electronics.

Comment: @Chad adjust 50 down to 15-20 and you'd be closer. I remember the saab my parent's owned growing up had its fusebox under the hood. And as Dan says, even a lot of modern cars have a separate fusebox under the hood. Audi is apparently a fan of putting them everywhere: An S5 has fuses on driver and passenger side, additional in the trunk, and the starter relay + fuses under the hood.

Answer (score 20):

Remove the publicly available key.

Make one copy of the key for each person or household who needs to be able to move the car. Give a key to each person and have them sign an agreement that they will not loan their key to anyone else.

If the individual is still able to move the car, he probably made an unauthorized copy, in which case you should contact the police.

I don't know what the cost of a parking ticket is in your area, but here I could make 30 copies of a key for less than one ticket.

Comment: Alternatively, put the "publicly available" key into a lockable key cabinet, and duplicate the keys to the cabinet. (I don't know about 2002 Ford Explorer, but not all car keys can be easily / cheaply duplicated. Key cabinet keys usually can.)

Comment: Definitely beats fumbling around inside the car's engine / electronics.

Comment: @DevSolar: true point, but thats simply the technical question OP asks.

Comment: Making duplicates of keys is just as much a technical solution as installing a kill switch or hiding a distributor. The real problem is this question is asking how to use automotive technology to solve a problem that can't be solved by any technology.

Answer (score 9):

As stated in other answers, you really need to get your new housemate to start listening to you.  If he doesn't respect your property, do you really want him living with you?

With regards to the vehicle, your simplest solution is unplugging something on the ignition side.  Historically, you could unplug the king lead (from the coil to the distributor) but as yours is likely on an electronic ignition system, I'd suggest unplugging the plug in the side of the coil pack or the sender unit for the inductive pickup that detects RPM.  I'm not 100% sure on your vehicle but I'd guess it would be screwed into the bell-housing taking a feed from the flywheel.

With these unplugged, the engine will crank but not start.  The problem here is, it's akin to hiding your keys because it means that you would need to know how to start the vehicle.

Comment: "the engine will crank but not start."  Aside from the problem of how you let other people move the car, the brain-dead idiot who is causing the problem will probably just keep trying till the battery is flat! (And *he* won't be the guy paying to replace the burnt-out starter motor, after he's done that every day for a month...)

Comment: Well thought of. Yes the starter will take a toll on the battery.

Comment: That's the point at which someone in the house wakes up, comes outside and chastises him.

Answer (score 5):

Remove fuse #26 (Brake-shift interlock) and the starter relay.  This will prevent the "friend" from starting the car, and will also prevent the "friend" from simply putting it in neutral and pushing it (The Brake-Shift interlock fuse being removed will prevent the shifter from being moved out of "Park").  Most people haven't got the slightest clue about fuse boxes in cars, so it should work fine.

Comment: Amazing, so if a fuse blows or battery is dead, the car is locked in position? This gets an award for brainlessness. Like car that wouldn't start with seatbelt unfastened.. Dumb.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply!  It's not locked in position, there's a procedure in the instruction manual for bypassing the Brake-Shift interlock.  Typically that's removing a small plastic cover near the gear shift and pushing down on a tab with a screwdriver, which will allow the car to be shifted out of park without using the brake pedal for use when towing or the fuse blows.

Answer (score 3):

Hide the keys in a different non-obvious place.

Tell all your friends the new place where the keys go, except for the one you don't want to move the car.

Answer (score 2):

Don't disable the vehicle. **Put up a set of dummy keys, which you can get from any junkyard with a similar-year Ford, it doesn't even have to be an Explorer.** The real keys you could hide somewhere, and inform the authorized drivers where they are.

Note that keys with plastic fobs may be damaged by applying ***too much force*** when trying to turn them in the external locks (door lock, hood lock). This may require a locksmith to retrieve the key blade from the lock. Thank you to [Steve Matthews](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/10927/steve-matthews) and [Numair Aidroos](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/29083/numair-aidroos) for bringing this up in the comments.

Comment: This may lead to costly repairs should your "friend" attempt to force the wrong keys into a lock barrel and snap the key blade off in the lock.

Comment: @SteveMatthews: Not at all. The ignition switch is designed to reject the wrong key without damage. Your "friend" would have to use beyond reasonable force to snap the key inside the ignition. Even if he did that, the plastic fob would fail before the metal key, which I expect could then be retrieved with needle-nose pliers.

Comment: They'd have to get through the door locks first.  I've snapped keys before.

Comment: @SteveMatthews: I've give you the door locks. I even recently saw a 2008 Focus in which the key broke off in the Hood Lock, a feature specific to the Focus.

Comment: I'm with Steve on this. I've seen pur driver do this to 3 of our cars in the last year. This damage requires tiny pins to be reinstated inside a lock barrel, unnecessary repairs. I Will not say it's a bad answer, just the con may outweigh the pro. It's my opinion not a theoretical fact.

Comment: Hiding the keys and informing only authorized drivers of their whereabouts is "weak" insofar as someone might (unwittingly or intentionally) "leak" the information, or the culprit could sniff it out. Putting up dummy keys serves absolutely no purpose except as "practical joke" (which is potentially harmful, see previous comments). And I personally wouldn't want to be playing games with a person like the OP described.

Answer (score 1):

As was said install a kill switch. This was originally relatively simple on older cars : fit a switch into the supply to the coil. However, you may find that a switch into the supply to the fuel pump would work - but the residual pressure may still allow him sufficient time to move the car. You will need to check, it will depend on the time between when your car was parked and when he tries to move it

Answer (score 1):

> My question, is there a way we can disable my truck so he can't move it onto a no parking zone by removing a plug or cap to disable our vehicle like in the movies?

The wire that they disconnect in the movies goes to the coil plug in a distributor cap like this:

[image: Distributor cap with incoming plug]

Source:  http://www.autohausaz.com/pn/03330

The wires from the outer plugs go to the spark plugs.  The central one brings the power in for all of them.  So removing the central wire will disable the vehicle.

They also might remove the distributor cap entirely.  Or they might unbolt it and remove the rotor from inside so that the spark doesn't travel from the coil wire to the spark plug wires.  Any of those involve unbolting the cap, which is more work than I'd want to do in this situation.

The 2002 Ford Explorer does not have that kind of distributor though.  It has an integrated ignition coil instead:

[image: Ignition coil for 2002 Ford Explorer]

Source:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYf_0zqS1RA

That video shows how to remove and replace the ignition coil.  It's not something that you'd do quickly.  It's a non-permanent way to disable a vehicle that you may be able to do without entering the vehicle (if you can release the hood).  A simpler method would be to unplug the six wires, but it's easy to put them back in the wrong order.  That can cause the engine to run incorrectly.  Unplugging some but not all the wires can allow the engine to run just well enough to reach a no parking zone but not well enough to drive.  Pretty much the opposite of what you want.

This is why [another answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/48043/32471) is recommending that you remove the starter relay instead.  That takes seconds to remove and replace once you know where it is.  If the orientation is not obvious, you can draw on the fuse box and relay with a marker to make it obvious which corner goes where.

The starter relay won't allow the starter to engage at all, so less chance of running down the battery, ruining the starter, or flooding the engine trying to start the vehicle.  The distribution just keeps the spark plugs from firing.  The starter will happily grind away.

A [kill switch](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/48038/32471) could also work.  But I wouldn't recommend installing it yourself unless you plan on working on the car yourself in general.  It's a mechanical (electrical) change.  Take the car to a mechanic or security system installer to get a kill switch installed.  Doing it incorrectly may not actually stop the car from starting or it may keep the car from starting more permanently than you want.  You need both off and on to work.

Answer (score 1):

Get a [boot](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071JZNKC2) ([heavy duty version](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XBXZ5JW)) for your car - make extra keys - pass out extra keys only to trusted roommates and not him.

But seriously: kick him out.